# Unknown column in 'field list' in prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I was asked to create a module that will limit the quantity of item purshased per group/customer.

So I decided to add another field to tbl_group and I named it "cart_limitQty" field. and i run a query in mysql and it successfully fetch my new field.. but when i query again in my newly created module.. this error appears.. and I tried all the related solution on other forums.. but still no luck..

and here is my query

```
$qry = 'SELECT `cart_limitQty` FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'group g
            INNER JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'group_lang gl
            ON g.`id_group` = gl.`id_group`  ';
```

and here is the code that i want to display the values..

```
<td><input type="text" value="" >{$row.cart_limitQty}</td>
```

Here are the actual errors:

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Unknown column 'cart_limitQty' in 'field list'

SELECT `cart_limitQty` FROM tbl_group g
                INNER JOIN tbl_group_lang gl
                ON g.`id_group` = gl.`id_group`
```

Comment: What is the exact message you get from Prestashop? How you run this query? I think there is too little info to solve your problem.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek thank you for the reply.. i already edited my post.

Comment: You should make sure you use in your prestashop the same database where you added `cart_limitQty` field. If you are sure, you should add `tbl_group` and `tbl_group_lang` schemas using for example http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: ow god!!!!!.... damn...thank you ..what a shame..yes i created the field in the wrong database..sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always make sure that your PHP script uses exact the same database where you test your code in mysql (probably using phpMyAdmin) and in your case it didn't so this was the real reason of your error.

Comment: sorry..i created too many database coz im learning prestashop..sorry again..but thanks for the time helping me..xD